# Create an online (video conference) class

Tags: gratis, web-apps, video-conferencing

Is there any free service to create an online class, video conference with about 35 students around the world?

I've done a [Google search for "web group video chat"](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+group+video+chat) and tried some of the results, but it seems that – if they offer group video chat at all – groups are limited to 12 people (Oovo) or less, others don't tell what the limits are.

I only need video conferencing, since exchanging documents, talk and chat, collaborative working etc. can be done using another tool that I've been using.

Answer (score 2):

The [MoodleCloud](https://moodlecloud.com/en/) could be your answer.

It is a free hosting service for the open source software moodle (as a teacher  you maybe already know it).

The magic keyword for your specific request is the integration of [BigBlueBlutton](http://bigbluebutton.org/).
This is an open source (and so free) web conference software.

Below the description from the website:

> BigBlueButton is an open source web conferencing system for on-line learning. BigBlueButton enables you to share documents (PDF and any office document), webcams, chat, audio and your desktop. It can also record sessions for later playback.

On their site you can find hosting partner for it, but they will be comercial. So the MoodleCloud will bring you the software as an online service for free (for up to 50 users).

If you do not like the MoodleCloud, try to search for other integrations of bigbluebutton. For example there is an (official) Plugin for Wordpress (which is also open source and so free to use, but you have to pay a hosing service)

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution since you only need video conference.

[zoom.us](https://zoom.us/)

Free for up to 50 people, but only "40 minutes per meeting"